# Giving style to a part of text in primefaces datatables

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I want to change the color of data in the datatable.

for eg :
a has two values... 64 and 64 .

a :  64

```
  64
```

b has two values 60 and 65

b  : 60

```
  65



<p:dataTable  var="someclass" value="#{someBean.someclass}">
<p:column headerText="DEVICE" >
<h:outputText value="#{someclass.somemember}" />
</p:column> 
<p:column headerText="PATH">
<h:outputText value="#{someclass.somemember}" />                              
</p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

if 'a' has two equal values then it should be displayed in one color else if values are different i need the data in different color.

How is it possible using primefaces datatable?

is there any other method using primefaces (without datatable) by which we can accomplish this?

his is how i want my expression to be like .......

if{#some.path eq "paths installed"} && some.path+1 eq "paths used)} 
then 
{if(#(some.path.substringAfter(':') eq (#(some.path+1.substringAfter(':')

... how to give this using jsf?

Comment: show your relevant `p:datatable` code , the `p:column` content

Comment: i have edited the content. please check it out

Comment: you mean that if  *DEVICE* memeber equals *PATH* member ?

Comment: No Dan. for a particular device there will be many paths. and if the subsequent PATH numbers for a DEVICE is same then the color change has to be done.

Comment: take it this way. forget the DEVICE thing. we have many PATH which is a list and is stored in a bean. we have to check two PATHS at once n change the color if it is same. ( P.S: have to compare 1st and 2nd paths, then 3rd and 4th, then 5th and 6th)

Comment: so how about writing some method to do the check and use it like that `styleClass="#{someclass.myMthodCheck?'equalMembers':''}"`

Comment: sorry Dan. unable to get you.

Comment: how the method to check be like? that is what i need. not getting any idea.

Comment: if for example you inspect a certain path, can you tell the following path? can you map them somehow and identify them later? I mean you probably will have to iterate them and each time by looking at current path you will have to compare it with the following one...

Comment: yes Dan. Im getting the paths using iterator. but how to differentiate?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most of what you need, at least you can get the general idea...

Your xhtml should look like this:

```
<p:dataTable  var="myLittleWrapper" value="#{myBean.modified}">
    <p:column headerText="PATH">
        <h:outputText value="#{myLittleWrapper.myObject.path}" styleClass="#{(myLittleWrapper.colorMe)?'equalMembers':''}"/>                              
    </p:column>
...
```

Create the following method (call it from you `@PostConstruct`)

```
List<MyObject> original = new ArrayList<MyObject>();//fill it with data
List<MyObjectWrapper> modified = new ArrayList<MyObjectWrapper>();// + getter/setter

public void prepareModifiedList() {

    ListIterator<MyObject> myListIter = original.listIterator();

    while (myListIter.hasNext()) {
        MyObject myObj = myListIter.next();
        MyObject nextMyObj = null;
        boolean colorMe = false;
        try {
            nextMyObj = peek(myListIter);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        }
        if (nextMyObj != null && myObj.getPath().equals(nextMyObj.getPath())) {
            colorMe = true;
        }
        MyObjectWrapper myObjectWrapper = new MyObjectWrapper(myObj, colorMe);
        modified.add(myObjectWrapper);

    }
}
```

Where `peek` method looks like this:

```
public <T> T peek(ListIterator<T> iter) throws NoSuchElementException {
    T obj = iter.next();
    iter.previous();
    return obj;
}
```

Where `MyObject` and `MyObjectWrapper`  looks something like this

```
public class MyObject {

    public MyObject(String path) {
        super();
        this.path = path;
    }

    private String path;

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```

And

```
public class MyObjectWrapper {
    MyObject myObject;

    boolean colorMe;

    public MyObjectWrapper(MyObject myObject, boolean colorMe) {
        super();
        this.myObject = myObject;
        this.colorMe = colorMe;
    }

    public MyObject getMyObject() {
        return myObject;
    }

    public void setMyObject(MyObject myObject) {
        this.myObject = myObject;
    }

    public boolean isColorMe() {
        return colorMe;
    }

    public void setColorMe(boolean colorMe) {
        this.colorMe = colorMe;
    }

}
```

---

If I understood you right that you can do something like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{someclass.somemember}" 
    styleClass="#{(someclass.someMember eq someclass.someOtherMember)?'equalMembers':''}"/>
```

where in your css add

```
.equalMembers {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan. I almost got it. path :12 23 34 45. and in the next line ill have : 12 23 34 56 .. next 3 n 4 lines will have paths with different data. the data I will be getting is the whole sentence. i mean "path:12 23 34 45.". So i need to take data only after colon (:) and then compare.